# .htaccess file is not working properly with slimphp framework

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, slim

I am using Slim php framework, having no .htaccess file in root folder I can call the pages 
like `/index.php/pagename`

but if I upload the following .htaccess file in the root folder I always get `403 Forbidden` error like `You don't have permission to access /hello on this server.`

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Are you sure the `.htaccess` file is being loaded?

Answer (score 4):

Try changing your rule to this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Then you can use a URI `/hello` which will be rewritten to `/index.php/hello`.

Answer (score 0):

Please review the [Route URL Rewriting](http://docs.slimframework.com/#Route-URL-Rewriting) 
section of the Slim documentation. The `.htaccess` provided there is different than those posted here.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```